# Half the size of Lego but only 1/3 the height

Tags: clone-brands

[image: 1×2 & 2×4 & Lego 1×2 in 6 colours]
I bought a batch of like Lego but small off eBay. I'd like to know what brand. The ×2's have tubes, but ×1's have no pillars. Colours like Lego, red, blue, light & dark bluish grey, B&W. Height little less than Lego plate, estimate 3•1mm instead of 3•2mm. Photo compared with Lego bricks, their 2×4's = the same size as a Lego 1×2 plate.

O! They are the same height as Nano Block, the white isn't quite as white.

Just bought some more the same. I believe it to be L'OZ. Basically I'm after what brand of Nano Blocks there are, came sans instructions. Other brands are Lele Brother & Wise Hawk.

Comment: Can you add a photo showing the shapes, dimensions, colours? Best would be to include known quantities like similar LEGO bricks in the image as well.

Comment: Can you (a) provide less fuzzy photos and (b) label the photos so we know which is the mystery brick and which is LEGO/Duplo?

Comment: @reviewers: it's the _photo_ that needs more focus, not the question, so please don't close it.